# Function to 'insert' a value to a specific position in stack class fails

Tags: python

I'm pretty new at Python (and in programming in general), trying to implement a stack class with a function to 'insert' a value v in any position p in the stack (even though its pretty wierd considering it's a stack). 
Here's my stack class:

```
class Stack:
  def __init__(self, maxSize):
    self.stack = list([])
    self.maxSize = maxSize
    self.size = int(0)
```

Here's my function to insert the value:

```
def addValToPos(self, position, value):
    temporaryList = [] # i tried to make a temporary list for every time the function was called

    for i in range(len(self.stack)):
        if i > position-1:
            temporaryList += self.stack[i]

    while self.size > position:
        self.pop() #removes the last position in stack (LIFO)

    self.push(value)

    for j in range(len(temporaryList)):
        self.stack += temporaryList[j]

    #del temporarylist <-- tried to delete the list in the end of the function
```

When i try to execute the function it works the first time, but the second time it doesn't (because i cannot delete the temporary list). I thought it would be best to make a `temoraryList` in the function, and then deleting it after the

Any thoughts on that, or how should i get rid of the variables in `temporaryList` after they have been added back to `self.stack` so that they come after the variable thet has been added?
Here's my function call:

```
maxSize = int(input("Enter max size: "))
stabel = Stack(maxSize)

while stabel.size != stabel.maxSize:
  value = input("Enter value: ")
  stabel.push(value)
stabel.print()

while True:
  if stabel.size < stabel.maxSize:
    que = input("Add value to pos? (yes/no)")
    if que.lower() == 'yes':
        position = int(input("Add position p: "))
        valToPos = int(input("Add value v: "))
        stabel.addValToPos(position-1, valToPos)
        stabel.size += 1
    else:
      break
  elif stabel.size >= stabel.maxSize:
    question0 = input("Increase the max size? (yes/no)")
    if question0.lower() == 'yes':
        addToMax0 = input("How much?")
        stabel.increase(addToMax0)
    else:
      break
stabel.print()
stabel.showSize()
print("Maxsize: ", stabel.maxSize)
```

Also, after the firs time through the while loop it does not seem to check if `self.size` is less than `self.maxSize`. Couldn't find that out either. 
BTW sorry if the code is hard to read, i had a little trouble pasting it in.

Comment: I see bugs in your `addValToPos`, but being unable to delete `temporaryList` is not one of them. That `del` would work fine (except for the capitalization typo), and it isn't even necessary; each call to `addValToPos` gets new local variables anyway.

Comment: The code you've shown wouldn't work the first time. Please post something we can actually run, that produces the behavior you describe when run, and post the complete output of running that code.

Comment: I know, posted the code further down. Should work to run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems quite overcomplicated. Python has this neat facility we call [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). One of the things it can do is alter a subsection of a list, including modifying its length. So we could write:

```
def addValToPos(alist, position, value):
    alist[position:position] = [value]
```

But that operation is already available as [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Other minor notes: `[]` creates a new list, `list([])` thus copies that empty list and then discards it. `int(0)` is similarly redundant, since `0` is already an `int`; this time there's no copy because `int` is immutable and partially interned.

It's also odd to have a full class for the stack, without defining any of its behaviour there. While Python's `list` and `deque` types cover stack functionality, an actual stack would have a much simpler set of operations; perhaps push, pop and isempty. As it turns out, your other snippets rely on these, and it is unclear what they do; this means this fails the Complete part of [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Now on to examining the intent of your code.

The `if` inside your first `for` means you should've started with a different range, since there are `position` iterations that do nothing. The good news is, [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) is perfectly capable of producing that type of range: `range(position, len(self.stack))` would have done it.

`temporaryList += self.stack[i]` probably doesn't do what you intend, because it takes one item out of the stack and tries to add it to `temporaryList`. Since the latter is a list, this will fail if the stack items aren't lists, and merge them if they are. So `stack = [[1], [2]]` will lead to `temporaryList = [1, 2]`. Perhaps you meant to use `list.append` rather than `+=` which works as `list.extend`.

Then there's a second pass that calls `pop` to remove items from `self`. This marks an implicit dependency that the prior access to `self.stack` reached the same items; it might if `self.push(v)` acts as `self.stack.append(v)`, but that's not known to me. Generally, it's a good idea to use the specific item as you pop it; for instance, pushing them onto another stack if we're doing an exercise using stacks specifically.

It looks like that whole set of intended operations could be replaced using two slice operations:

```
temporaryList = self.stack[position:]
del self.stack[position:]
```

Then the restoring loop again performs the flattening operation by extracting items and extending.

I don't really have an idea why you think you need to delete `temporaryList`; it is a local variable and will only exist for each call. You haven't shown us how that breaks, either, so we're lacking information on what you observe and expect.

I think I'll stop guessing at this point.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, i'll check out what you said!

Answer (score 0):

I see i didn't post a runnable code. Hope this helps more:

```
class Stack:
def __init__(self, maxSize):
    self.stack = list([])
    self.maxSize = maxSize
    self.size = int(0)

def push(self, value):
    self.stack.append(value)
    self.size += 1

def print(self):
    for i in range(len(self.stack)):
        print(self.stack[i])

def addValToPos(self, position, value):
    temporaryList = []
    if self.maxSize <= self.size:
        self.maxSize += 1
    for i in range(len(self.stack)):
        if i > position-1:
            temporaryList += self.stack[i]

    while self.size > position:
        self.pop()

    self.push(value)

    for j in range(len(temporaryList)):
        self.stack += temporaryList[j]
        #temporaryList.pop()


while True:
if stabel.size < stabel.maxSize:
    que = input("Add value to pos? (yes/no)")
    if que.lower() == 'yes':
        position = int(input("Add position p: "))
        valToPos = int(input("Add value v: "))
        stabel.addValToPos(position-1, valToPos)
        stabel.size += 1
    else:
        break
elif stabel.size >= stabel.maxSize:
    question0 = input("Increase the max size? (yes/no)")
    if question0.lower() == 'yes':
        addToMax0 = input("How much?")
        stabel.increase(addToMax0)
    else:
        break
stabel.print()
stabel.showSize()
print("Maxsize: ", stabel.maxSize)
```

**Output**

```
Enter max size: 4
Enter value: 1
Enter value: 2
Enter value: 3
Enter value: 4
1
2
3
4
Increase the max size? (yes/no)yes
How much?1
1
2
3
4
Size: 4
Maxsize:  5
Add value to pos? (yes/no)yes
Add position p: 2
Add value v: 9
1
9
2
3
4
Size: 5
Maxsize:  5
Add value to pos? (yes/no)
```

Here i also struggle, because Size and Maxsize is the same (5), but it stops at the first if-statement at the while True-loop even though `self.size` and `self.maxSize` are the same. My intention was to increase `self.maxSize` at this point on the elif-statement. Probably a noob question, but been struggling for a while with that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason i thought i had to delete `temporaryList` after running the function the first time, is because when i run the code that i posted over the second time, i get this output:

```
Enter max size: 6
Enter value: 1
Enter value: 2
Enter value: 3
Enter value: 4
Enter value: 5
Enter value: 6
# printing the numbers in self.stack
1
2
3
4
5
6
Increase the max size? (yes/no)yes
How much?2
# printing the numbers in self.stack
1
2
3
4
5
6
Size: 6
Maxsize:  8
Add value to pos? (yes/no)yes
Add position p: 2
Add value v: 9
# printing the numbers in self.stack
# this is the output i want
1
9
2
3
4
5
6
Size: 7
Maxsize:  8
Add value to pos? (yes/no)yes
Add position p: 1
Add value v: 8
# printing the numbers in self.stack
# here i don't know what happened
1
9
2
3
8
1
9
2
3
4
5
6
Size: 12
Maxsize:  8
Add value to pos? (yes/no)
```

Instead i would only want to increase with the one number added in, like the first output i got. Thanks in advance